# How do I write a Query to join two tables based on minimum absolute time difference?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help writing a MySQL query to do a matching with the tables below.
So far my query looks like this:

```
SELECT event.id, event.eventid, upload.uploadid
FROM event
LEFT JOIN upload
ON(event.id = upload.id and event.timestamp <= upload.timestamp);
```

The second condition in my join, `event.timestamp <= upload.timestamp`, is a placeholder until I can figure out a boolean expression (or something else) to get the desired result. I'm lost on how to write a statement to join based on minimum absolute time difference. The tables have the following structure:

Event table

| id | eventid | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| u1 | event1 | 2020-01-01 01:30:00 |
| u1 | event2 | 2020-01-01 01:45:00 |
| u2 | event1 | 2020-01-01 05:30:00 |
| u2 | event2 | 2020-01-01 05:39:00 |

Upload table

| id | uploadid | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| u1 | upload1 | 2020-01-01 01:30:00 |
| u1 | upload2 | 2020-01-01 02:30:00 |
| u2 | upload1 | 2020-01-01 05:30:00 |
| u2 | upload2 | 2020-01-01 05:35:00 |

The query needs to match every event in the event table to the closest upload from that respective user.

The desired result of the query is:

```
u1 event1 upload1
u1 event2 upload1
u2 event1 upload1
u2 event2 upload2
```

EDIT:
The following query produced the the desired result:

```
SELECT e.id, e.eventid, 
        (SELECT u.uploadid
        FROM upload u
        WHERE (u.id = e.id and u.timestamp < e.timestamp)
        ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, u.timestamp, e.timestamp))
        LIMIT 1) 
FROM event e;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the `uploadid`, then I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT e.*,
       (SELECT u.uploadid
        FROM upload u
        WHERE u.id = e.id
        ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, e.timestamp, u.timestamp))
       ) as uploadid
FROM event e;
```